# Structure initialization with repmat

Tags: matlab, struct, initialization, vectorization

I want to initalize structures and it seems to be too slow. **How** do I do it with **repmat**, which is supposed to be a much faster solution in Matlab?
Originally:

```
for i=1:30
    myloc.one.matrixBig(i,1).matrixBig= zeros(6,6);
    for j=1:5
      myloc.one.id(i,j) = 0;
      for k=1:10
          myloc.one.final(j,k).final(i,1) = 0;
      end
    end
end
```

**EDIT:**

```
   for j=1:30
       for i=1:10 
          myObject{i,j}.s = zeros(6,1);
          myObject{i,j}.f = zeros(6,1);
       end
   end
```

Also, am I able to make it faster by adding some [] initialization even before, or is that limit of my optimization possibilities?
Thanks very much for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the equivalent vectorized code of the first code snippet:

```
myloc.one = struct('id', zeros(30, 5), ...
  'matrixBig', struct('matrixBig', repmat({zeros(6)}, 30, 1)), ...
  'final', struct('final', repmat({zeros(30, 1)}, 5, 10)));
```

or alternatively:

```
myloc.one = struct('id', zeros(30, 5), ...
   'matrixBig', repmat(struct('matrixBig', zeros(6)), 30, 1), ...
   'final', repmat(struct('final', zeros(30, 1)), 5, 10));
```

Choose the one you like most.

As for the second (edited) part, it can be replaced with:

```
myObject = repmat({struct('s', zeros(6, 1), 'f', zeros(6, 1))}, 30, 10);
```

Note that there is no need to preallocate anything because there aren't any explicit loops here.

Comment: Thanks, can you please answer a solution for the case I updated in my post, with cells? I feel bad I ask such trivial questions, but in this case matlab help does not work good for me in explaining ..

Comment: yes of course I will gladly do that! Can you please update one more time and say where to change if I had .s and .f arrays inside the cell? Thanks. Where to learn how to operate with repmat?

Comment: @beginh The best way to learn about the syntax is reading the [official MATLAB reference documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/) (here are the links to [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html)).

Comment: thanks so much! i needed it urgently, but now I will learn for myself so that I dont ask all things.

Comment: @beginh No problem :) but you should know that there's really no point in a cell of structs. An array of structures accomplishes the same effect and more, and takes less memory (than a cell-array of structs). If you remove the curly braces (`{}`) in the second part of my question, you'll get your array of structures.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this case the first question is why are you using a cell array of structs. One of the fundamentals of matlab is that everything can be vectorised. So instead set up a matrix of structs.

```
% Define the empty struct, struct itself is vectorised   
myloc=struct('s',cell(10,30),'f',cell(10,30));
%Assign values
[myloc(:).s]=deal(0),[myloc(:).f]=deal(0);
```

A matrix of structures is a far more powerful datatype. For example if you want to extract a single row of the field in to a vector you can simply use the following syntax

```
sRow8=[myloc(8,:).s]
```